# How to send Differential UART signals in C

Tags: c, verilog

I am working on a project where I want to send UART signals to a camera using a C application running on an FPGA. Previously I've been sending UART commands using system call write(). However, while this works on my simulated serial ports I created using minicom, I am not sure if this would work on a camera using the CameraLink standard since the specification states that UART signals are LVDS across two pins (one pin is UART_P and another is UART_N).

My question is how can I create a serial connection to send UART commands to this hardware in C. Can I open two I/O channels using termios and write my command to UART_P and a complemented version of my command to UART_N? Or should I maybe write it to my verilog module which can in turn write the bytes to the positive pin and the complemented bytes to the negative pin? Or is there a better way to do this?

Edit: apparently, this question is too broad but I don't know how to add more to what I'm asking. I feel like it is a simple question: How do I send a differential UART command in C?

Is there some way to make two ports: one that corresponds to the positive pin and the other to the negative pin do something like:

```
int fdp, fdn;
fdp = open(uart_p);
fdn = open(uart_n);

uint16_t cmd_p = [some value];
uint16_t cmd_n = ~[some value];

write(fdp, cmd_p, sizeof(cmd_p));
write(fdn, cmd_n, sizeof(cmd_n));

close(fdp);
close(fdn);
```

Alternatively, I have a verilog module on the fpga that could take the bytes from the C program and convert them to LVDS signals and send them to the UART pins. Has anyone worked with camera link before or done something similar? I am not sure what the best way is to send differential uart commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is rather "open" so I can't give an exact answer but I think I can at least steer you in the right direction.

If your camera UART is LVDS (very unusual anyway!) then you should make the UART output channel LVDS compliant. Most FPGAs, certainly the bigger ones, have special LVDS I/O cells.

Normally you have to instance such an LVDS cell from the FPGA I/O library. Every FPGA vendor has an I/O library and you should look for the FPGA I/O application note.

Whatever: you do NOT change the software. The LVDS I/O cell has a single input and two, complementary outputs. The inversion is done in hardware. Also beware of what voltage levels you need. There are numerous LVDS standards with different voltage swings. Check your camera data sheet.

Last but not least: check what the UART receive channel needs. You might need an LVDS receiver there too.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! I found some FPGA library calls that should do the LVDS processing for me and I think that is what I will do: have the C program tell the verilog on the FPGA to send those bytes. I checked the camera data sheet and I found an area labeled: LVDS receiver specifications. And under this section is info under the header: Differential input voltage. Is this the correct place to look?

Comment: Yes, make sure the FPGA and camera differential voltage are the same. You can often specify the type of LVDS driver when you instantiate the I/O cell.